# How to replace standard error messages on own in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have languages file `form_validation_lang.php` with a standard errors messages in array.

I added some own messages here:

```
$lang['my'] = "Enter vacancy name";
```

I have form validation:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('vacancy', 'here load text from field my', 'required');
```

I want to display only text from `$lang['my']` when my field is not filled.

Comment: Having never done this, my first guess would be to create your own version of the system language file `form_validation_lang.php` in the application directory.

Comment: you can use $this->form_validation->set_message();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set messages for certain rule, make form_validation.php inside application folder as @Craig mentioned above:

```
$lang['form_validation_required']       = 'Yep, that {field} is required and has custom message.';
```

You can place rules message inside controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('integer', 'There must be an integer.');
```

And you can also set message for one of the rules among others:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Your email', 'required|valid_email',
    array('valid_email' => 'Watch out, it should be email')
);
```